# what is use Of @root.__ in node js and how to use

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-handlebars

I have download node js project but I don't know why they use  @root.__. actually, I am new in node js

```
<label for="userEmail">{{ @root.__ "User email" }} *</label>
```

Comment: I know nothing about Express or Handlebars but I've found this naming convention in other tech stacks to refer to translation functions so it probably means «display "User email" in current locale».

Comment: Thank You so much @ÁlvaroGonzález